# Reason for this output?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out the reason for false output. It works absolutely fine for all values from 0 to 10000 except for values ppp, pppp, qqq and qqqq. The output should be -3,-4,3 and 4 respectively. But on executing this code the output is -5,-5,5 and 6 respectively. Can anyone help me out in this ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a;
    int x=0;
    cin>>a;
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='p')
        x=x-1;
        if(a[i]=='q')
        x=x+1;
    }
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to access nonexistent elements of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior unless you enter a string at least 10,000 characters long. The only element outside the string that you're allowed to access is `a[a.size()]`, which returns a null character (`'\0'`). Anything beyond that is undefined.

Change your loop to:

```
size_t len = a.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

so you don't go outside the string.